# Adding video id dynamically to the youtube player object

Tags: javascript, android, webview, youtube-iframe-api

I have an android app which plays YouTube videos in a webview. I want to change the video id when the user changes the playing video. Here is my code,

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[1];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player; var stime; var etime; 
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'ia8CKDIur3s',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });


  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    if(event.target.a.id == "player"){
        event.target.playVideo();
    }
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.

  var done = false;
  function play(){
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "working";

    player.loadVideoById({videoId:'ia8CKDIur3s',
                  startSeconds:stime,
                  endSeconds:etime,
                  suggestedQuality:'large'});
  }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if(etime!=null){
        play();
        etime=null;
    }
  }

  function getStartTime() {
    stime = player.getCurrentTime();
    document.getElementById("start").innerHTML = stime;
  }

  function getEndTime() {
    etime = player.getCurrentTime();
    document.getElementById("end").innerHTML = etime;

  }
  </script>
```

The user can also selects a part of the video by specifying start and end time and play that video segment on the same Youtube player.

I need a way to pass the video id to this html code from Android activity.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need a text input that stores the ID in the HTML,
this is after the initialization code you've run above.

Inside an Onclick="" of an HTML element:

```
document.getElementById('YouTube-video-id').value='DrQRS40OKNE';
youTubePlayerChangeVideoId();
```

And then in your JS Script

```
function youTubePlayerChangeVideoId() {
  'use strict';
  var inputVideoId = document.getElementById('YouTube-video-id');
  var videoId = inputVideoId.value;
  var quality = $("#quality-selector option:selected").text();      
  youTubePlayer.cueVideoById({suggestedQuality: quality,
  videoId: videoId
});
}
```

here's the quality selector I used

```
<select id="quality-selector" class="uk-input">
  <option>small</option>
  <option selected="">medium</option>
  <option>large</option>
  <option>hd720</option>
  <option>hd1080</option>
  <option>highres</option>
</select>
```

I'm still a novice at the Youtube Api but this code is live at [my personal Youtube Library](http://ajotto.co.za/heroes)

My code is a little messy but not obfuscated in any way so you are welcome to inspect the page and browse the JS, it still has a way to go.